# ¿Como quitar o ocultar o registros duplicados de dos tablas de detalle con una tabla maestra en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
    CREATE TABLE `COMPRAS` (
      `codigo` CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `periodo` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `mes` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
      `numero_indicador` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `rut` CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `tipodocumento` SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL,
      `nombre` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
      `nrodoc` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `fecha` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
      `afecto` DOUBLE(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `exento` DOUBLE(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `iva` DOUBLE(15,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `total` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `cuenta` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `glosa` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      `credito_valor` DOUBLE(15,0) DEFAULT '0',
      `ivaretenido` DOUBLE(15,0) DEFAULT '0',
      `ivanorecibido` DOUBLE(15,0) DEFAULT '0',
      `direccion` VARCHAR(90) DEFAULT NULL,  
       PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`,`periodo`,`mes`,`numero_indicador`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    CREATE TABLE `DETALLE_IMPUESTOS` (
      `id_detalleimpuestos` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `codigo` CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `periodo` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `mes` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
      `numero_indicador` INT(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `imptoadic` SMALLINT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `pctadic` DOUBLE(5,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
      `valadic` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_detalleimpuestos`)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


    CREATE TABLE `DETALLE_COMPRAS` (
      `id_detallecompras` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `codigo` CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
      `periodo` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `mes` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
      `numero_indicador` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `cuenta` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `centro` SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `num_docto` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `valor` INT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `glosa` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_detallecompras`)
      ) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Donde la tabla compra es la maestra y las otras dos, son de detalle. Cuando el cruce de la tabla padre con una de ellas, es aceptable que se me repita en la tabla padre, pero cuando el cruce de las tres, se me repiten mucho los registros, quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La query que hago es la siguiente:

```
    SELECT l.codigo,l.periodo,l.mes,l.numero_indicador,l.rut,l.tipodocumento,l.nombre,l.nrodoc,DATE_FORMAT(l.fecha,'%d-%m-%Y') 
    AS fecha,l.afecto,l.exento,l.iva,l.total,l.cuenta,l.glosa,l.credito_valor,l.ivaretenido,l.ivanorecibido,l.direccion, 
    dlp.id_detalleimpuestos, dlp.pctadic,dlp.imptoadic,dlp.valadic,dl.id_detallecompras, dl.cuenta,dl.centro,dl.num_docto,dl.valor
    FROM COMPRAS l LEFT JOIN DETALLE_COMPRAS dl ON l.numero_indicador=dl.numero_indicador AND l.mes=dl.mes AND l.periodo=dl.periodo AND l.codigo=dl.codigo
    LEFT JOIN DETALLE_IMPUESTOS dlp ON l.numero_indicador=dlp.numero_indicador AND l.mes=dlp.mes AND l.periodo=dlp.periodo AND l.codigo=dlp.codigo 
    WHERE l.codigo='22-ene' AND l.periodo=2016 AND l.numero_indicador =110001 GROUP BY dlp.id_detalleimpuestos, dl.id_detallecompras ;
```

Como hago para que no se me repitan los registros que estan marcado en rojo segun la imagen.

NOTA: las tablas de detalles tienen las claves foraneas codigo`,`periodo`,`mes`,`numero_indicador

La tabla COMPRAS tiene un registro con n registros de tabla DETALLE_IMPUESTOS y con la tabla DETALLE_COMPRAS p registros. La tabla compra es el encabezado de las tablas de detalles

Comment: ¿Cómo es la relación entre las tablas? ¿"Compra" es 1 a 1 con las otras dos?

Comment: las tablas de detalles tienen las claves foraneas codigo`,`periodo`,`mes`,`numero_indicador

La tabla COMPRAS tiene un registro con n registros de tabla DETALLE_IMPUESTOS y con la tabla DETALLE_COMPRAS p registros

Comment: En la tabla DETALLE_IMPUESTOS no tenés para el código "22-11" 3 registros con id_detalleimpuestos diferentes (1,2,3)? En ese caso, cómo sabe la consulta cuál poner? Salvo que definas un criterio siempre te va a traer todos los registros. No es determinista. Podrías pensar en un campo en particular (por ejemplo el mayor, menor, etc), pero si no lo definís, no tiene manera de saber qué traer y qué no.

Comment: es de 1 a M. Edite la pregunta, el codigo no es 22-1, es 22-ene

Comment: Ok, igual para lo que te comenté es lo mismo.

Comment: No se si entendí mal, quieres decir que sería imposible obtener registros no duplicados? para la tabla COMPRAS y DETALLE_COMPRAS siempre va a traer registros, pero la DETALLE_IMPUESTOS puede darse el caso que no traiga.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48697/discussion-between-pablo-claus-and-danilo).

Comment: ¿Puedes proveer una muestra de los datos de las 3 tablas, luego proveer el resultado de tu consulta con esa muestra, y el resultado deseado? Pero te diré que no es buena señal el que tu consulta seleccione tantas columnas que no forman parte del `group by`. Eso no es buen diseño.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estás teniendo tiene que ver con que las tablas detalle son 1 a M con la tabla `COMPRAS`, por lo que no va a ser posible "eliminar" de la consulta los registros "duplicados". Es más, si agregaras otra tabla a la consulta, los duplicados crecerían.

Para obtener los resultas como los querés, deberías **separar en tres la consultas**.

Una consulta por cada tabla filtrando por el campo `codigo`.

Esto te garantiza que no tengas registros duplicados.

Una vez obtenidos las tres consultas, podés cargar los objetos en la aplicación y mostrarlos como desees.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero dijeron que se podía logra hacer lo que podía creando tablas temporales y usando cursores. Pero de ahí no sabría muy bien como hacerlo

Comment: Te vas a complicar innecesariamente.

Comment: si, quisiera hacerlo así de fácil, pero el que pidió, dijo que se podía así y no puedo llevarle la contraria porque el lo desea así

Comment: Lo pude hacer con cursor, se hace el cruce con dos tablas, después se valida en el loop si debo insertar o actualizar en una tabla temporal que le agrego un id autoincremental

Comment: No entiendo por qué hacerlo así, si se puede hacer sin cursores. Pero bueno, hacelo como a vos te parezca más cómodo.